# Why is $\mathbb{Z}$ a free algebra in the class of abelian groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, free-groups, universal-algebra

Following "Term rewriting and all that" page 47, I find that $\mathbb{Z}$ is free in the class of all Abelian groups being generated by $X = \{1\}$.

The definition of free is:

> Let $\Sigma$ be a signature, $X$ be a set, $\mathcal{K}$ a class of
>   $\Sigma$-algebras. The $\Sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ is free in
>   $\mathcal{K}$ with generating set $X$ if:
>
> 1. $\mathcal{A}$ is generated by $X$ with $\mathcal{A} \in \mathcal{K}$.
> 2. For every $\Sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}$ in $\mathcal{K}$ every mapping $\phi:X \to B$ can be extended to a homomorphism $\hat \phi:
>     \mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{B}$.

The candidate mapping is $\phi: \{1\} \to B$ would be of the form $1 \mapsto g$ with $g$ in the abelian group $B$. However, $g = 1$ since any homomorphism has to respect operations and in particular, distinguished constants in the algebra, so it should be $1 \mapsto 1$ in order for an extension to exist.

Why then is $\mathbb{Z}$ a free algebra in the set of abelian groups?

Comment: What this means is if $G$ is **any** group and $g\in G$, then there is precisely one group homomorphism $f:\Bbb Z\to G$ with $f(1)=g$.

Comment: A general abelian group does not have an element $1$.

Comment: Notice that $1$, as an element of $\mathbb{Z}$, is not the neutral element (that one is $0$). The reason I think you're making this confusion (and that's perhaps what baffled you in first place) is that, contrary to your claim following 'However...', you don't need that $1 \mapsto 1$ in this case; what you need is $0 \mapsto 1$ because $0$ is the $1$ of $\mathbb{Z}$. Moreover, the neutral element could never generated anything but the trivial group...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comments, I figure out the situation.

First, abelian groups don't need to have a unit.

Second, this just states that the map $\phi: 0 \mapsto g$ is extended to an homomorphism naturally as $n \mapsto ng$ since one realizes $(n+m)g = ng+mg$ (I don't think that distributivity can be used here but instead some kind of induction).

With this definition we get an homomorphism $\hat \phi$ which is all that is asked in the definition. Afterwards, we realize that this extension has to be unique as these holds in general for extensions that coincide in a generating set of a $\Sigma$-algebra.